# Search function with multiple optional parameters (Client and API)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

I'm relatively new to API and MVC and I'm still learning. I have only finished the basics of Web API and Client MVC (GET,PUT,POST,DEL) by retrieving (all) data, updating, adding and deleting. This is the main guide that my teacher uses for lessons.
http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-1

I'm currently on term break and am exploring on my own. I've came across a certain task which was to display a list of items through a filter of 10 or so parameters, and most of them are optional fields.
Fields: Name, shape, color, signature, product code, etc.
Most of the fields are nullable except for a selected few which are drop lists.

Most guides and tutorials would give me examples of 1, or maybe a few parameters but this task requires more than that.

The problem here is that I don't know how to pass so many parameters from an MVC client over to an API. I've read alot of other solutions that it is possible to pass them as URI

```
baseuri/action?a=&b=&c=1&d=example
```

But how can I ignore empty fields that never have been filled and only search for the ones that are actually filled in a database?

```
baseuri/action?a=&b=&c=1&d=example

//ignoring a and b
var result = from b in db.table where (c==1 && d==example)
```

My teacher hinted me to make my own controller and function but I'm not so sure how to go about it.

There are certain solutions which suggested me to use [FromURI], but the search function is too complex and I'm not too sure how to work with [FromBody] either.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

To ignore empty fields you can make parameters nullable and filter by them only if they have value. For example:

```
public IQueryable<Row> Action(string a, bool? b, int? c, string d)
{
   var result = db.table.Where(e => true);
   if (a != null)
       result = result.Where(e => e.a == a);
   if (b.HasValue)
       result = result.Where(e => e.b == b.Value);
   if (c.HasValue)
       result = result.Where(e => e.c == c.Value);
   if (d != null)
       result = result.Where(e => e.d == d);
   return result;
}
```

As a solution for 10+ parameters I can suggest something like this:

```
public IQueryable<Row> Action()
{
  var result = db.table.Where(e => true);
  foreach(var parameter in HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(ActionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query).ToKeyValuePairs())
  {
    switch(parameter.Key)
    {
      case "a":
        result = result.Where(e => e.a == parameter.Value);
        break;
      case "b":
        result = result.Where(e => e.b == parameter.Value);
        break;
      ...
    }   

  }
  return result;
}
```

or check query for required parameters and filter base on it's value

Comment: But wouldn't be super inefficient because I'm handling 10+ or so parameter? This solution looks fine for a few parameters, but not so much for 10+ parameters to handle.

Comment: It that case you can use `ActionContext.Request.RequestUri.Query.ParseQueryString()` (extension method in `System.Web.HttpUtility`) to get NameValueCollection on query parameters and filter result base on this values inside of a loop

Comment: I've added example in answer, please have a look

Comment: Though, for
    case "b":
        result = result.Where(e => e.a == parameter.Value);
        break;
Is that supposed to be e.b instead of e.a ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, my mistake